# PictureBox and HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, image, cookies, httpwebrequest, captcha

I want to use PictureBox to show user CAPTCHA image. I know how to set typical image from URL. But I need to add CAPTCHA which need cookies. Exactly I say about this: https://konto.interia.pl/poczta/nowe-konto.

I don't know how can I hold cookie from this server, which I can use later to display captcha, and after that send special response to create an account. Have you any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Use `CookieContainer`.

Comment: I know that i should use it, but i don't know how to connect CookieContainer with that special captcha image. My problem is because [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx) required String as parameter, not HttpWebRequest which use CookieContainer.

Answer (score 1):

Download Image using `HTTPWEBREQUEST` and save Cookies what ever you want to do with them. Then simply load that picture into picture box its simple as that. Get is answered by users if thats what you want and send the answer with `Cookies` and `CaptchaID`. That should do it.

Comment: I agree with that. Problem is other. This captcha doesn't have static ID and also when in web browser we don't have stored cookies with that, image doesn't appear. Look at that link: [captcha link](https://captcha.interia.pl/73D22B5D3294BA783FD7F0D7D5174123.jpeg)

Comment: So go to the main page save cookies, then download image using cookies whats the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the image yourself and put it in the PictureBox; you can't use its built-in downloader with cookies.

Use `HttpWebRequst` to download it to a `MemoryStream`, then call `Image.FromStream()`.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. But when i want get response in that code:

`HttpWebRequest requestPic = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            requestPic.CookieContainer = cookies;

            WebResponse responsePic = requestPic.GetResponse();
            webImage = Image.FromStream(responsePic.GetResponseStream());`

I get some exceptions.

Comment: Exception:Thrown: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." (System.Net.WebException)
A System.Net.WebException was thrown: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Comment: @matikycz: That's a problem with your server (you probably messed up the cookies, or need a User Agent).  Compare to a working session in Fiddler.